# Symfony3 bad routing for css

Tags: php, web, symfony

**Prehistory**:
I've created CRUD for entity, and now trying to apply my styles to that CRUD's pages.
**My problem looks like**:

[image]

As you see css-files are loading from "/mannapp/vdservers", but they should be loaded from "/".
*What should I do?*

**Routing for this page**:

```
manapp_vdservers_index:
   path:   /manapp/vdservers/
   defaults: { _controller:MainBundle:VDServers:index }
   methods:  [GET]
```

**Links for assets looks like this**:

```
<link href="css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Actually all of my routes with level more than 1 works bad:

- **/page** - *css* will be loaded well
- **/page/page1** - *css* will be loaded from */page/css*

Comment: Same unresolved problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194433/symfony-2-css-and-js-not-loaded-using-fosuserbundle-routing-bad-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path in `href` is relative (it doesn't start with `/`). This means that `css/general.css` is added to *the current URI* (***not** the location of the template*). So when visiting a page on URI `/something/foo`, the stylesheet is loaded from `/something/css/general.css`.

What you need is an absolute path: `/css/general.css`.

To fix things even more, you can use Symfony's [`asset()` helper function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating#linking-to-assets). This function expects one argument, which is a path relative to the `web/` directory of your application.

So change your line to either `<link href="/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">` or `<link href="{{ asset('css/general.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` (recommend).

Comment: Thanks. I though solution would be less obvious, may be kind of global parameters that I've missed, but way with `{{ asset('css/general.css') }}` looks strong.